# Retreiving specific (conditioned) data from a database? Program crashes

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, string

I've developed a small chat system that works fine trough TCP on my LAN.

Afterwards I started to design a small system which recognizes the user by its machine name. The machine name is associated with the user inside the DB table Users. This works beautiful when I try it on the PC I developed it on.

I am sure in one thing: The program crashes on other PCs on the network after its machine name has been found in the DB, which means it's not a database connection problem. Why is it crashing on other PCs?

```
public void LogInTroughDB()
{
    string serverName = "10.255.2.140\\ADMIN\\adminDB,1433";
    string userID = "admin";
    string password = "admin";
    SqlConnection cnn;
    string connetionString = null;
    connetionString = @"Server=" + serverName + ";Initial Catalog=master;User ID=" + userID + ";Password=" + password;
    cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
    try
    {
        cnn.Open();
        //MessageBox.Show("Connection Open!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Error!");
    }

    string sqlquery = ("SELECT * FROM dbo.Users WHERE (machine_name ='" + machine_name + "')"); ;
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, cnn);
    SqlDataReader sReader;
    sReader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while(sReader.Read()) {
        first_name = sReader["first_name"].ToString();
        last_name = sReader["last_name"].ToString();
        userNameText.Text = first_name + " " + last_name;
    }
}
```

When the program is started on another PC in the network, if its machine name is in the database, it should log in the user to the chat room and allow him/her to send messages.

Comment: You really need to parametrise that query; never inject the values in a SQL query (unless you are properly quoting them, which you are not, but still, parametrisation is far better).

Comment: Show full error info please.

Comment: Okay, new problem (the same problem but with some more insight), the program runs and does everything i need when started from Visual Studio but not as standalone. Only crashes when started outside IDE.

Comment: You should probably start by adding some error handling.  Google Try/Catch blocks.

Comment: Your error handling is useless - your code eats the error and displays a meaningless message box. Presumably your app has more of this - so you need to fix the error handling first simply to be able to determine what is causing the crash.

Comment: Oh, okay, thank you for the suggestions. Obviously Im a student learning OOP and c#, didn't mean to come off as a know it all.

Comment: A couple suggestions. As mentioned you need to learn how to use parameters. Especially since you are still learning this is the time before you learn bad habits. Parameterization is not one of those "best practices", it is crucial to building a data driven application. Sql injection is very real, and it is very awful to deal with. My friend [bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) will tell you all about it. Second is that you should wrap anything inheriting the IDisposable interface in a USING statement. (Connections, commands, datareaders, etc)

Comment: The other thing you should do is put your connection string in the config file. Make it the entire connection string, not separate values for username, password etc.